# jquery performance issue

Tags: jquery

I am running into some jquery performace issues. I am having a select dropdown with a class name as 'dropdownClass'. In some cases, I did not want to display dropdown so instead I using the hidden variable with the same class.

Here is the [link to the sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/S5SGt/1/).

Right now in the above example, I have only 4 rows, so everything looks fine. But on my project, I am working with lot more rows, and around 7 columns. I want to know if there is a better way I can get to select the elements with class 'dropdownClass'. I see I have no other choice than to use $('.dropdownClass') because I have two different tags using it. I am getting an error whether to stop the script on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, should make it a bit faster:

```
$(function(){
    $('select.dropdownClass,input.dropdownClass').each(function(){
        var ddval = $(this).val();
        //alert(ddval);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using each use javascript's native FOR loop.

**jQuery's each function takes over 10 times as long as JS native "for" loop.**

Source
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551

PS: Tried it in my current project and it works! :)